# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a Django project and essentially I have written a model which stores user details. They complete this profile after they have signed up and I have a Boolean in the User model which states whether they have completed this custom profile yet so I can make changes in the template.

When the form for the second profile page gets submitted I would like it to update the Bool from False to True but I am getting the error:

```
'bool' object has no attribute 'has_created_artist_profile'
```

See code below:

**views.py**

```
def ArtistEditView(request):
    artist = Artist.objects.get(user=request.user)
    current_artist = request.user
    artist_status = current_artist.has_created_artist_profile

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArtistForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=artist)
        if form.is_valid():
            artist_status.has_created_artist_profile = True
            artist_status.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('artist_home'))
    else:
        artist_dict = model_to_dict(artist)
        form = ArtistForm(artist_dict)
    return render(request, 'artist/artist_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class ArtistForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        exclude =['user', ]
```

Any one able to suggest a better way to update this / to get rid of the error?

Comment: rather than setting `artist_status`, couldn't you just use `current_artist.has_created_artist_profile` instead? Your problem is that you set `artist_status` to `current_artist.has_created_artist_profile`, and then try and do it again.

Comment: Thanks @RobertSeaman good spot! Stupid on my part. Have removed the `has_created_artist_profile` from `artist_status` so now essentially have `artist_status = True
            artist_status.save()
            form.save()` but still getting same error message

Comment: I think you should remove `artist_status` entirely - it's adding confusion. I imagine you want to do `current_artist.save()` instead. How comes you created `artist_status`? Are you trying to do something without affecting the `current_artist` object?

Comment: Dude that totally worked! Thanks so much. Just iterated on current_artist and all is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'bool' object has no attribute 'has_created_artist_profile'` means you're trying to access the attribute `has_created_artist_profile` of a boolean object (`True` or `False`), rather than that of an object.

For example:
`True.has_created_artist_profile` will produce the exact same error.

From your code, you set `artist_status` to that of a boolean which was part of an object (`current_artist`), and then tried to access a property from that boolean.

As advised, you have removed the `artist_status` variable, and you are now using the `current_artist` object directly.

Comment: Thanks Robert this really helped! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The Python `"AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute"` occurs when we try to access an attribute on a boolean value (True or False). To solve the error, track down where you are setting the value to a boolean or use the `hasattr()` method to check for the attribute's existence.

Here is how the error occurs.

```
 artist_status.has_created_artist_profile = True
```

You are trying to access an attribute on a boolean (True or False) instead of on the object. If you print() the value you are accessing the attribute on, it will be a boolean. So you need to track down where exactly you are setting the value to a boolean in your code and correct the assignment.